# How to disable the message "reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for xxx failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!"?

Tags: ssh, dns, openssh

I have a "OpenSSH_7.2" client connecting to a "OpenSSH_7.3-hpn14v5 FreeBSD-openssh-portable-7.3.p1,1" server hosted on a dynamic IP. The remote server is a NAS4free server.

I tried to apply the suggestions I found online and I added via WebGUI to the NAS4free sshd_config the following lines:

```
UseDNS no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

The client also has in sshd_config the same lines.

The message is still there. I have no access to the inverse DNS record, so I cannot change it.

I perform "quiet" remote rsync backups and the output is being sent by mail, since it only contains errors and warnings. I get an email every time for errors that are of no use in my case.

How should I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client appears to be calling the DNS check, therefore

> UseDNS no
>
> GSSAPIAuthentication no

on the server are useless.

The DNS check in the client has been introduced (apparently) with a GSSAPI patch introduced for compatibility with SunSSH [the file https://github.com/omniti-labs/omnios-build/blob/master/build/openssh/patches/0015-GSS-API-key-exchange-support.patch#L1652 is no more available online

Adding

> GSSAPIKeyExchange no

to ssh_config (not sshd_config) solved the issue.

See also: https://www.mail-archive.com/omnios-discuss@lists.omniti.com/msg07240.html

Comment: links return 404 or host not found, can you update the links?

Comment: @Jasonw The patch is gone, I cannot find it anymore. If you want you can search for the history of OpenSSH under OmniOS... I updated the link to the mailing list

Comment: Works for me with UseDNS no, leaving GSSAPIAuthentication yes. Make sure you reload or restart sshd after changing the configuration file.